# Quando "return" é diferente de "return await" em uma função assíncrona no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, promises

Estava fazendo uma revisão de MR e vi um teste parecido com este:

```js
it('...', async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('...')
      .send({ /* ... */ })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        // expects ...
        resolve();
      });
  });
});
```

Minha dúvida é se esse `await` faz alguma diferença no comportamento do código uma vez que não há nenhuma lógica após ele.

Outra dúvida é se é necessário marcar a função como `async` uma vez que uma promise já está sendo retornada explicitamente. O código anterior tem o mesmo comportamento do código abaixo?

```js
it('...', () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('...')
      .send({ /* ... */ })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        // expects ...
        resolve();
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Resumidamente, o `return` é diferente de `return await` quando está dentro de um bloco `try`.

---

No caso específico da pergunta, não há diferença. Ali, `return` é o mesmo que `return await` porque está fora de um bloco `try` (que é onde a diferença acontece).

No entanto, há alguns casos em que pode haver diferença. Na maioria das vezes, é a mesma coisa. Contudo, é importante saber quando `return` e `return await` são diferentes, uma vez que o comportamento do código pode ser ligeiramente alterado.

#### O que é `async`?

Quando você marca uma função como `async`, ela *sempre* retornará uma `Promise`. No caso de um erro for lançado dentro dessa função assíncrona, a promessa retornada será do tipo `rejected`. Caso contrário, resolver-se-á com algum valor. No caso de não se utilizar um `return` explicitamente, será retornada uma promessa resolvida com valor `undefined`.

No geral, é ideal utilizar funções assíncronas apenas quando você utiliza um `await` explícito dentro delas. Caso contrário, o código pode acabar sendo contraintuitivo para alguns que não conhecem propriamente o comportamento das funç~oes assíncronas.

Se você só quer *retornar* uma promessa (como no código da pergunta), não é necessário utilizar `async` ou `await`, já que não há real necessidade em se *aguardar* a conclusão da promessa.

#### O operador `await`

O operador `await` só pode ser usado dentro de funções marcadas como assíncrona. Ele basicamente *espera* pela conclusão da promessa passada a ele:

- Caso a promessa for resolvida, ele "desempacotará" o valor de dentro da `Promise`, que será o valor retornado pela expressão.
- Caso a promessa for rejeitada, ele lançará o erro, que pode ser capturado em blocos `try`/`catch`.

A partir desse segundo item da lista acima, é possível inferir a diferença entre o `return` e o `return await`.

#### Retornando uma promessa — `return <promise>`

Considere o exemplo abaixo, em que temos uma função assíncrona `foo` que chama uma função `waitAndMaybeReject`, que retorna uma promessa que pode se resolver com qualquer valor ou rejeitar com algum erro.

```
async function foo() {
  try {
//  ↓↓↓↓↓↓
    return waitAndMaybeReject();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}
```

A função `waitAndMaybeReject` retorna uma promessa. No entanto, `foo` não aguarda de fato pela conclusão dessa promessa. A função `foo` simplesmente retorna (imediatamente) a `Promise` retornada pela aplicação de `waitAndMaybeReject`. Nesse caso, ocorre uma "delegação" da promessa.

Como a promessa foi *retornada* antes de ser, de fato, resolvida ou rejeitada, pode-se afirmar que o `try`/`catch` é inútil ali, porque, mesmo que `waitAndMaybeReject` rejeite-se com algum erro, o `catch` não será capaz de capturá-lo, uma vez que a promessa já terá sido retornada para quem chamou `foo`.

#### Retornando o valor de uma promessa concluída — `return await <promise>`

Agora, considere este código (ainda com a mesma função `waitAndMaybeReject` do exemplo anterior):

```
async function foo() {
  try {
//  ↓↓↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓↓
    return await waitAndMaybeReject();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}
```

Note agora que, como foi utilizado o operador `await`, estamos de fato aguardando a conclusão da promessa retornada por `waitAndMaybeReject`. Desse modo, no caso da promessa retornada por `waitAndMaybeReject` for rejeitada, o bloco `catch` será capaz de capturar a exceção.

A promessa, com o `return await` não foi delegada por `foo` a seu chamador. Ao contrário: a promessa foi *aguardada* por `foo` e seu valor resolvido (ou rejeição) foram propriamente tratados por `foo`.

Note que agora `foo` retorna o valor *resolvido* pela promessa que `waitAndMaybeReject` retorna, *OU* `"caught"`, no caso da rejeição da promessa em questão.

#### Conclusão

De modo geral, `return await` só faz diferença quando o `return` é envolvido por algum bloco `try`/`catch`.

Se você precisa tratar o valor que será concluído por uma promessa *antes* de ser de fato retornado, utilize `return await`. Caso contrário, `return` (delegar a promessa) não faz diferença, já que, como vimos, toda função assíncrona sempre retorna uma promessa.

Friso que não há diferença em tempo de execução. A diferença de fato está onde a promessa irá ser concluída.

Pessoalmente, não gosto de usar `return await` porque as pessoas não costumam entender de fato essa diferença (muitas vezes por nem saber que ela existe). Convenhamos que o JavaScript é e sempre foi uma linguagem com um enorme número de diferenças sutis como esta.

O código a seguir tem o mesmo efeito que `return await`. A diferença é que, ao meu ver, é mais claro:

```
function foo() {
  try {
    const val = await waitAndMaybeReject();
    return val;
  }  catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}
```

É o mesmo que:

```
function foo() {
  try {
    return await waitAndMaybeReject();
  }  catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}
```

Cabe a você decidir qual prefere.

Como o `return await` só tem efeito diferencial quando está dentro de blocos `try`/`catch`, o ESLint fornece uma regra chamada [`no-return-await`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) que cuida disso para você.

#### Não acredito em você, mostre-me isso tudo!

Veja o exemplo funcional abaixo:

```js
fooWithReturn(true)
  .then((resolvedValue) => console.log('1 fooWithReturn(throw).then =', resolvedValue)) // <não executará>
  .catch((errorValue) => console.log('1 fooWithReturn(throw).catch =', errorValue)); // Erro não tratado!

fooWithReturn(false)
  .then((resolvedValue) => console.log('2 fooWithReturn(dont throw).then =', resolvedValue)) // Yay!
  .catch((errorValue) => console.log('2 fooWithReturn(dont throw).catch =', errorValue)); // <não executará>
  
fooWithReturnAwait(true)
  .then((resolvedValue) => console.log('3 fooWithReturnAwait(throw).then =', resolvedValue)) // caught
  .catch((errorValue) => console.log('3 fooWithReturnAwait(throw).catch =', errorValue)); // <não executará>

fooWithReturnAwait(false)
  .then((resolvedValue) => console.log('4 fooWithReturnAwait(dont throw).then =', resolvedValue)) // Yay!
  .catch((errorValue) => console.log('4 fooWithReturnAwait(dont throw).catch =', errorValue)); // <não executará>

async function fooWithReturn(shouldThrow) {
  try {
    return waitAndMaybeReject(shouldThrow);
  } catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}

async function fooWithReturnAwait(shouldThrow) {
  try {
    return await waitAndMaybeReject(shouldThrow);
  } catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}

function waitAndMaybeReject(shouldThrow) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (shouldThrow) {
        reject('Erro não tratado!');
      } else {
        resolve('Yay!');
      }
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

---

Os exemplos desta resposta foram baseados no artigo "[await vs return vs return await](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/)", de Jake Archibald.

Answer (score 2):

A função deve ser marcada como `async` quando existe uma chamada explícita a um `await` dentro dela. Ela pode ser livremente marcada como `async` quando queremos executá-la assíncronamente, mesmo quando ela não possui nenhum statement `await`.

Quanto à dúvida se o `await` faz diferença, a resposta é: não. Porém, se a função apenas retorna uma `promise`, não faz sentido usar o `await` antes, pois perde completamente o sentido. Nesse caso, o melhor mesmo é apenas retornar e deixar quem chamou resolva a `promise`, fazendo uso corretamente das chamadas assíncronas.

Um `await` depois de um `return` é contra-intuitivo, uma vez que o JS resolve a promise para então retornar uma nova promise (duas promises, mas apenas um valor resolvido de fato). Portanto, a boa prática é sempre retornar direto e deixar quem chama resolver (a menos que você queira adicionar um tratamento, mas aí não faria um `return` diretamente).

Comment: Fiz alguns testes aqui, mas não consegui constatar essa "perda de tempo" a qual você diz existir. O código rodou "ao mesmo tempo" com e sem a delegação. Poderia tentar exemplificá-la mais concretamente?

Comment: Ah, a perda de tempo é muitíssimo sutil. A menos que seja uma chamada realmente custosa (como uma chamada HTTP), você não vai perceber mesmo. E mesmo que seja chamada HTTP, a perda de tempo ocorreria se outra função pudesse finalizar no tempo que ele esperou essa promise resolver. Quando falo "perda de tempo", é sobre como o interpretador JS funciona. Ele vai "perder um tempo" resolvendo, só então vai retornar. Ele poderia simplesmente retornar e estaria tudo certo. Mas como disse, é sutil e só perceptível em grande escala de processamento.

Comment: Mas o _tempo de espera_ está associado a quem irá aguardar, de fato, a resolução da promessa. E não creio que a função que (de fato) faça essa espera tenha alguma diferença. Não faz diferença se função `a` aguarde ou se função `b` (chamada por `a`) aguarde. Afinal, uma vez que já se tenha o valor, não é necessário aguardar por ele novamente. Como já diz a matemática, a ordem dos fatores não altera o produto. Se, realmente, houver diferença de tempo, será infinitesimal, mas não creio que estará associado ao custo da chamada (como em HTTP), mas sim ao fato de se ter uma função a mais na pilha.

Comment: Mas a função `a` não sabe que tem o valor, mesmo que `b` já tenha resolvido. É uma nova promise. Por isso mesmo a má prática. A menos que o JS seja otimizado para isso (eu realmente não sei), são dois tempos. A diferença é que o tempo de resolução é super ínfimo, mas faz uma diferença danada quando você tem centenas de milhares de chamadas resolvendo algo realmente custoso, como chamadas HTTP, conexões de banco e etc.

Comment: Então, o HTTP já foi superado, mas o tempo de resolver a promise, voltar o estado e retornar à pilha, não. Se eu fico perdendo um único tempo toda vez, isso se acumula. E quando acumulado é custoso.

Comment: Eu achei que tivesse respondendo quem fez a questão na minha primeira resposta kkkkkk mas sim, você deve saber tudo que falei e talvez questione essa perda de tempo. Mas ela realmente existe. Inclusive fiz trabalhos de refatorações em `returns` por perceber um mal comportamento de uma aplicação quando era entupida de requests. Talvez o framework utilizado que não estivesse muito bem desenhado, mas conseguimos receber mais requisições por segundo.

Comment: Uma nova promessa será, de fato, criada, mas nesse ponto (sem delegar a promessa), o valor já é conhecido, portanto, tempo de espera é único não é cabível ou justificável aguardar por algo que já se possui. Ademais, o JavaScript, estando pautado em chamadas assíncronas (cada vez mais atreladas às promessas), não poderia permitir esse tipo de _delay_. Por isso insisto que não há diferença de tempo (no que tange ao tempo de se esperar a conclusão da promessa).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116174/discussion-between-igor-cavalcanti-and-luiz-felipe).