# Node JS - Função com return não passa os dados

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando fazer uma API bem básica, para aprender, mas não consigo entender porque o `return` de uma função que pega dados do BD não os retorna para o outro módulo.

Estou usando Knex e ES6:
Este módulo (`Controle`) chama a função `AtividadesTodas()`, que está no módulo `models`:

```
// Seleciona todas as atividades
    async todosRegs(req, res){
        var listaAtiv = await Atividades.AtividadesTodas();
        if(listaAtiv != undefined){
            res.json(listaAtiv);
        }else{
            console.log('lista vazia');
        }
        
    }
```

No módulo `Models`, nesta função, os dados ficam armazenados na variável `data`, tanto que podem ser exibidos no console, mas, aparentemente, estes dados não retornam, pois cai sempre no `else`, ou seja variável `undefined`:

```
 async AtividadesTodas(){
        await knex('Atividades').select('AtividadeDesc').orderBy('AtividadeDesc').then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);            
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

A maneira correta e utilizada é da seguinte forma retornando o [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises) e no [node](/questions/tagged/node) resolver e trazer a resultado, ***exemplo***:

```
AtividadesTodas() {
    return knex('Atividades').select('AtividadeDesc').orderBy('AtividadeDesc');
}
```

e no [node](/questions/tagged/node):

```
async todosRegs(req, res) {
    try {
        const listaAtiv = await Atividades.AtividadesTodas();
        if(listaAtiv != undefined) {
            res.json(listaAtiv);
        } else {
            console.log('lista vazia');
        }   
    } catch (e) {
       // error
       console.log(e);
    }
}
```

*Faça uma boa leitura nessa resposta:* [Quando “return” é diferente de “return await” em uma função assíncrona no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482034/54880)

Comment: Muito bom. E parece aquele problema que muitos cometem de misturar `await` com `callback`. Só faltou um `try/catch` para tratar possiveis erros  do `AtividadesTodas`.

Comment: Verdade @CmteCardeal ...

Comment: Adicionado @CmteCardeal ...

Comment: Vale lembrar que nesse caso o `return await` é redundante (é o mesmo que `return`). [Referir a esta outra pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482034/69296)

Comment: Então @luizfelipe até o async é desnecessário?

Comment: Se a função não utilizar `await` em nenhum outro lugar (apenas retornando a promessa), não é necessário não. :-)

Comment: vlw @LuizFelipe retirei e deixei retornando somente a `builder` pra resolver o `promise` fora